# Generate an XLS file from JSON and send it on HTTPS response

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

So in an HTTPS Cloud Function i am fetching an array of Objects from my database and from this i want to generate a XLS file and send it on the response. I am using the [js2excel](https://github.com/dwqs/js2excel) library but it doesn't generate a download file.

```
const json2excel = require('js2excel');

exports.getUserOnXlsFile = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {
        return getFromDataBaseHelper()
        .then(listFromDatabase =>{
            try {
                var xlsFile = json2excel(listFromDatabase);
                res.send(xlsFile);
            } catch (e) {
                console.error('export error', e);
                res.status(500).send(e);
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error getting chefs:', error);
            res.status(500).send(error);
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: @n ReferenceError: Blob is not defined

Answer (score 1):

I find a workaround like this:

```
exports.getUserOnXlsFile = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {
        return getFromDataBaseHelper()
        .then(response =>{
            try {
                const csv = json2csv(response)
                res.setHeader(
                  "Content-disposition",
                  "attachment; filename=UserList.csv"
                )
                res.set("Content-Type", "text/csv")
                res.status(200).send(csv)
            } catch (e) {
                console.error('export error', e);
                res.status(500).send(e);

            }

        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error getting user:', error);
            res.status(500).send(error);
        })
    });
});
```

Not great, not terrible.